# 'rand' function in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, random

I'm trying to make a death predictor that has a random chance for your character to die as your progress. I'm going to make it have multiple chances to die as well as higher chances the older you grow. How do I fix this basic rand function, to make it so int RandomFactor has a 1-20 number and activates randomly to kill you (sorry if this sounds sadistic)?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int RandomFactor;
    RandomFactor = rand();
    20 % 1;

    for (double count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
        if (count < 20) {
            Sleep(360);
            cout << "\n\t\t\tIt's your birthday! You turned: " << count;
        } 
        else
            if (RandomFactor == 1) {
                cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tBANG! You're dead!";
            }
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `RandomFactor = rand(); 20 % 1;` try `RandomFactor = rand() % 20;`.

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: expected a ';' c:\Users\Parent\Desktop\DeathPredictionv1\DeathPredictionv1\DeathPredictionv1.cpp 18 24 DeathPredictionv1                      That's the error message I get If I do that. :(

Comment: Intellisense may be intelligent but it is not psychic. It can't predict when you want to make a calculation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rand % 20` but it won't be truly uniform, it will contain bias. Your better option in C++ is to use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` this way

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen( rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis( 1, 20);

    for ( int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069874/1141471) to learn more about the bias introduced by `rand() % x`.

Comment: The bias at this scale is acceptable for pretty much everything except statistics and encryption: low numbers are only 0.0061012812% more likely than high.

Comment: I am not sure about your result and we are talking about general case

Comment: @MooingDuck: If the language already has support for much better randomness why settle for an inferior pattern? Also note how this example seeds with a value that can potentially provide more randomness than `time()` (which could be the same inside precision for different threads/cluster nodes/...).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: Because I can never recall all the bits for this generation, but can always remember `rand()` :/

Comment: @0d0a: You mentioned `rand()%20`, plus an alternative, so I gave you an upvote.  `RAND_MAX` is `32768` or higher, so worst case, 0-7 are picked 1639 times, and 8-19 are picked 1638 times (8*1639+8*1638=32768).  Then 1639/1638-1 shows that low numbers are picked 0.061050061% more than higher numbers.

Comment: I consider this as an error to use rand%20 when you have correct behavior available to use as a std::uniform_int_distribution, it doesn't matter that bias will be 1%, 5% or 0.01%. Apart from this, how did you calculated this (is this in accordance with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069874/1141471)?)

Answer (score 3):

C++ allows you to discard values at your will, so when you do

```
20 % 1;
```

It doesn't complain as it calculates it and simply tosses the value.

Perhaps what you meant was in fact:

```
RandomFactor = rand() % 20;
```

However, that will result in a number in the range [0, 19], so you probably wanted to add 1:

```
RandomFactor = (rand() % 20) + 1
```

So now both ends of the range will be increased by 1, resulting in [1, 20] inclusive.

---

Furthermore, the if statement

```
if(count < 20)
```

will **always** be true while you are looping (that *is* the loop condition after all), so the `else if` will never be run.

Comment: I would also say that the original implementation doesn't seem to accomplish the goal because the call to rand() is outside of the loop, so it will have the same value for each loop iteration.  Either everybody is dead or nobody is

Comment: @rdowell Perhaps `RandomFactor` is calculating whether or not there will be a zombie apocalypse, in which case that would be correct. Who's to say?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `drand()`, it will return a uniform number between 0 and 1, which you can then scale. Which you can initialize with `srand48(seed)`. For example, if you want a 20% chance to trigger you could do:

```
 if( drand() <= 0.05f ) // (5% chance)
     // do something
```

Or alternatively

```
int randomNumber = ceil( drand()*20 ); 
// creates a uniform distribution between 1 and 20, inclusive
```

Answer (score -3):

There shouldn't be a semi-colon after rand().  Try RandomFactor = rand() 20 % 1;

Comment: **-1** That will most definitely result in a syntax error.