# C++, certain combos never appear using rand()

Tags: c++, random

I'm using rand() for two ints, between 0 and 2. It appears that the first int is never 0 while the second int is 2. Here is my test code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int number1, number2;
    number1 = rand() % 3;
    number2 = rand() % 3;

    printf("%i, %i", number1, number2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output-25 tries

```
2, 2
2, 2
2, 1
1, 2
0, 1
2, 2
1, 2
1, 0
2, 1
1, 0
0, 0
1, 2
2, 2
0, 0
2, 1
1, 0
2, 2
1, 0
2, 1
1, 0
0, 1
1, 2
1, 0
0, 0
2, 2
```

As you can see, out of 25 tries, the combo was never 0, 2. Is this the sign that I should probably move over to < random >? In addition, there is never 2, 0.

Comment: Consider calculating the probability of what you see if the sample was truly random and make your decision based on that. Not sure why there's a downvote on this question...

Comment: Only 25 samples?  That's nowhere near enough to evaluate the distribution.

Comment: You are aware that running the program twice within a second will output *exactly* the same numbers?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9df0a85c7f6624f)

Comment: @CitricThunder [Works here, too.](http://ideone.com/2YdHk2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should definitely use `<random>`. The sooner you forget about `rand`'s existence, the happier you will be.
2. `rand` is sometimes implemented with a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). LCGs suffer from a number of defects, the most relevant being that that the low-order bits of sequentially generated numbers are highly correlated. For this reason, you should never use `rand() % k` to generate numbers in the range `[0, k)`. There are other reasons. In fact, generating unbiased random integers from a restricted range involves some subtleties, which `<random>` handles for you.
3. `srand(time(NULL))` seeds the random number generator to the current time in seconds from epoch, which means that if you run the program several times in sequence, the seeds will be either the same or similar. If the seeds are the same, the random number sequence will also be the same. If the seeds are similar, the random number sequences may also be similar. So don't do this except in long-running programs. Finding a good seed for a pseudo random number generator can be tricky. `<random>` implementations will have better default behaviour, so you won't normally need to worry about this.

Comment: +1. Also, Eric Lippert has a [good post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/) on why the remainder technique introduces bias.

Comment: @IlianPinzon: Or you could watch stl's preso on channel9: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 3):

No, this will happen for 9*(1-1/9)^25 = 0.4736 of all seeds, or roughly 50% of the time. That is, some two digit sequence with digits in {0,1,2} will be missing from your first 25 results roughly half the times you run your program.

Run it again and see what happens.

Comment: Running the above code in an online compiler gives the combos, but I never get them in my compiler.

Comment: Q: What is your compiler?  Q: Define "never"?  25 times?  50 times?  1000 times?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I've run it about 150 times without a for loop, since the for loop results in the combos. But without a for loop, I haven't seen them in 150 tries.

Answer (score 1):

It is. This code gave me 0,2 pair just at first run:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  number1 = rand() % 3;
  number2 = rand() % 3;
  printf("%i, %i\n", number1, number2);
}
```

Generating truly random number from uniform distribution doesn't guarantee that given (possible) number will appear in limited number of trials. The K2 out of four [BSI criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) of good PRNG is

> K2 — A sequence of numbers which is indistinguishable from 'true
>   random' numbers according to specified statistical tests.

thus generating pseudo random numbers ofcourse tends to behave in the same way as sampling from true  random distribution - though because of limitations any (possible) number will appear at some point (at time less or equal its period).

http://ideone.com/c5oRQL

---

### Use std::uniform_int_distribution

Apart from the above `rand()` is not the best generator. It introduces bias always whenever the divisor in modulo operation doesn't evenly divides the range of PRNG. Operator % makes the probability distribution produced in this way skewed because RAND_MAX which is maximum value for `rand()` can be not equal to k * 3 + 2. If divisor not evenly divides the range then distribution will be skewed and the bias increases with divisor. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069874/1141471) more on this. Summing it up: in C++ you should use `<random>` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen( rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis( 0, 2);

    for ( int n = 0; n < 25; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking % 3 does not depend on just lower order bits.

I ran the program below using VC++ simulating running the OP's program ten million times with one second between invocations. It shows no bias.

```
start = 1413167398
(0, 0) 1110545
(0, 1) 1111285
(0, 2) 1111611
(1, 0) 1111317
(1, 1) 1111666
(1, 2) 1110451
(2, 0) 1111580
(2, 1) 1110491
(2, 2) 1111054

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> counter;

    unsigned int start = static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(nullptr));
    std::cout << "start = " << start << std::endl;
    unsigned int finish = start + 10000000;
    for (unsigned int seed = start; seed != finish; ++seed)
    {
        std::srand(seed);
        int x = rand() % 3;
        int y = rand() % 3;

        ++counter[std::make_pair(x, y)];
    }

    for (auto iter = counter.cbegin(); iter != counter.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << iter->first.first << ", " << iter->first.second << ") ";
        std::cout << iter->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```